# Entity Framework 4 & Partial Class Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework-4

I havea simple EF Model with a Test entity and I want to make use of partial classes to add validation like this:

```
namespace WebApp.Model
{
    using WebApp.BusinessRules;
    using WebApp.BusinessRules.Rules;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;

    [HasSelfValidation]
    public partial class Test : BusinessObject
    {
        public Test()
        {
            AddRule(new ValidateRequired("Title"));
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

Partial declarations of 'Model.Test' must not specify different base classes.

I understand the error but how can I use EF4 Models and still have access to all my business validation goodness?

BusinessObject has all the validation and stuff, so if I can get them working happily together, I'm all done. Hope someone can help.

Richard

Comment: Can't you make it so that BusinessObject will inherit the EF base class first before inheriting business object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup (using default EF EntityObjects) there is no way that you can get your entities inherit from *BusinessObject*. Instead of inheritance you can use Composition though, which means each partial class would have a field of *BusinessObject* type. 

If you want to stick to your inheritance, then you should use [*EF 4 POCO Entitie*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) instead and then have your POCOs to inherit from *BusinessObject*.